# UCWA Get presence from user outside my organisation

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I'm trying to get the presence of a user outside my organisation using UCWA Rest. But I always get a None availability response.
The federation is working because I can get it with SfB client.

When I send the request: GET https://webpooldb41e07.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/101092958/people/xxx@xxx.com/presence

I have the following response

```
{"availability":"None","deviceType":"Unknown","_links":{"self":{"href":"/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/1010929584/people/xxx@xxx.com/presence"}},"rel":"contactPresence"}
```

I dont find any help on the official documentation. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea:

Normally the remote company need to accept your request. Once both account are "connected" you can see the presence from the user. If the request isn´t accepted the status remains unknown.

So depending on your construct it could be that the taskuser you are using never send out such a request or it wasn´t accepted.